# How to uninstall homebrew cask and the other stuff it came along with it?

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

I installed cask on homebrew on my M1 chip Mac since I wanted to try out the whole being able to update software with ease. But, after some testing I did not really find it useful to me for the time being.

I went ahead to uninstall cask with `brew uninstall cask` but when doing `brew list` I get all of these other packages that were installed with cask. I reinstalled cask just in case and it went smoothly (took way less time than before).

```
brew list
bdw-gc      gmp     libevent    nettle      readline
c-ares      gnutls      libffi      nghttp2     unbound
cask        guile       libidn2     openssl@1.1
emacs       jansson     libtasn1    p11-kit
gettext     jemalloc    libtool     pcre2
git     libev       libunistring    pkg-config
```

I know I only had **git**, **gettext** and **pcre2**. I am not familiar with any of the other ones and would like to know if I would have to `brew uninstall <package>` the other ones or just leave it alone. If there is a way to uninstall or delete cask in a way that removes the packages I did not say I had before. Would like to hear your advice on what to do or if I should just leave cask itself as-well and go on with my day.

Still a beginner therefore apologies if I said anything odd.

Comment: If you run out of space, then undelete everything and install only what's needed. Otherwise - does it bother you, makes something incompatible? If not - leave it and focus on something actually important.

Comment: Fair enough, I see no point of trying uninstall as well